# OpenCart theme development: Price as number?

Tags: opencart

I need to display some products differently depending on their price. I hoped that I could simply check the value of the `$price` variable from within the relevant theme file(s), but `$price` contains a currency formatted string. And because OpenCart supports a variety of currency formats, there's no simple, robust way of converting price strings back into numbers.

I've looked in the product controller class, `ControllerProductProduct`. So far as I can tell, OpenCart does not expose a numeric price value to views. I could modify the controller class, but I'd rather not because it would complicate updates.

Have I overlooked something? Is there no easy way to perform a numeric comparison on a price from within an OpenCart theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no, OpenCart does not expose numeric price values to themes. You will have to modify core files, which Brad [explains how to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661314/opencart-theme-development-price-as-number/11377844#6512572).

Comment: If Brad explains how to solve this, I would have selected *his* answer. :-)

Comment: I hear what you're saying, which is why I mentioned his answer, but my question specifically excludes modifying system files. Once you've made even the slightest modification, you can no longer perform blind updates. You have to manually merge every new version of OpenCart with your custom version. You also can't distribute your theme as a self-contained package. It's a pain that I really wanted to avoid!

Comment: @Metaphile: vQmod was created for the exact reason of the blind update issue. It's also possible to get the price value in a template without modification. You can use the `$product_info` variable

Answer (score 7):

Looking at v1.4.9.4 in product.php (`ControllerProductProduct`) I can see the following code that sets the formatted value of $price that you're talking about:

```php
if ($discount) {
    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($discount, $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
} else {
    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'],$result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
```

Why don't you change this to be the following...

```php
if ($discount) {
    $price_num = $this->tax->calculate($discount, $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'));
    $price = $this->currency->format($price_num);
} else {
    $price_num = $this->tax->calculate($result['price'],$result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'));
    $price = $this->currency->format($price_num);
```

And then a few lines down from this, you can then pass on this $price_num value to the template by adding the following:

```php
$this->data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id'    => $result['product_id'],
    ...
    'price'         => $price,
    'price_num'     => $price_num,
    ...
```

Should do what you need